# How can I say "pick-up from the hotel"?

Tags: translation, nouns

I am translating a trip schedule for a group of Japanese people coming to visit my country. I translated "pick-up from the airport" as "空港へのお出迎え", but I think お出迎え can only be used when you greet someone the first time they have just arrived in a place. I don't think it can be used to translate "pick-up from the hotel" for a later moment. Is ピックアップ understandable by Japanese people? Also, I need a noun and not a verb, since the schedule is written as a list, something like this:

> 09:00 Pick-up from the airport
>
> 18:00 Pick-up from the hotel

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had better not use a word ピックアップ because it is not a common word in Japan.

I think お出迎え is appropriate, and I want to change it a little like 空港までお出迎え.

Another phrase I think of is 空港まで送迎車を手配, but it is a little businesslike.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I can use お出迎え also for a later moment, not only for their arrival?

Comment: I think お出迎え can be also used for a later moment. If this schedule list is for Japanese people, 空港で送迎車に乗車 may be also used.

Comment: @Tommy You don't have to worry because it doesn't make sense to Japanese speakers as long as it's used in that meaning.

Comment: Eheh, I know but just today I was in the subway and read an ad of a gym saying: このチャンスにベストなコンディションを。I don't worry about now, I worry about the future. Probably 50 years ago also the sentence above wouldn't make any sense, that's what I mean.

Comment: @Tommy I agree with you, but I think the tendency doesn't change because English will be more spoken in Japan in future.

Comment: Even Japanese people are sometimes fed up with katakana words for English words. Japanese people may think that using English words is cool.

Comment: @YuuichiTam Not so much cool as indirect and less intuitive so that you can blur things.

Answer (score 1):

I think Yuuichi's answer is good. Just want to add that maybe you also want to have a look at 迎{むか}えに行く・迎えに来る. It's probably less formal than お出迎え so it depends on the situation. Anyway, 迎{むか}えに行く is quite good to know. For example:

> 私は空港に彼を迎えに行きます。 I will go pick him up at the airport.
>
> 明日の朝私を迎えに来るのを忘れないでね。 Don't forget to pick me up tomorrow morning.

The answer ends here, the following is just a side note. I will put it in italic just to underline it is somehow unrelated to the actual answer. It is just a remark born out of your attempt of using ピックアップ.

*In general, I strongly advocate against trying to "katakanize" everything when we do not know a word. Chances are there are perfectly fine native Japanese words that we simply don't know. This is just my opinion but I am very much against the modern tendency of abusing loan words in Japanese.*

Comment: As you said, the suggestions you provided are less formal and I would use them inside a sentence, not on a trip schedule written as a list. But thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: @Marco sure I just wanted to add something as your question seemed to be quite asking in general how to say “to go and meet/pick up someone somewhere”. I don’t understand why the down vote anyway, did you do it?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I upvoted it now since it still adds useful information.